# Using Static & Dynamic Libraries In Embarcadero C++ Builder

Tags: c++, c++11, c++builder, delphi-xe8, c++builder-xe8

I have an iOS static library (.a & .h file) and would like to know how to implement it into a C++ Builder project. The documentation cover's how to import a Java library in some detail but does not touch on a third party iOS library at all. Nor are there any blog posts or video's from Embarcadero about doing so.

The closest post I have found is:

[Checking for an internet connection on mobile devices with Delphi XE5](http://delphi.radsoft.com.au/2013/11/checking-for-an-internet-connection-on-mobile-devices-with-delphi-xe5/)

However, it is not clear how to link in the .a file and then how to access the interface in the ObjC .h file.

Any help would be appreciated, and will share the completed version with Embarcadero Community so they will hopefully document how to do this eventually.

Comment: Static libraries are a bit easier to use in C++ than in Delphi. Simply add the `.a` file to your project (or use a `#pragma comment(lib, filename.a)` statement in your code), `#include` the `.h` in your code where needed, and call the library's functionality as needed.  In Delphi, there are no `.h` files, so everything in the `.a` file has to be declared manually in the Delphi code.

Comment: Thanks! If the .h is in ObjC with types such as NSString will one not have to create an interface to communicate with this? I see a lot of the precompiled headers have GUID's for libraries although I cannot figure out how to get the GUID for the library if I wanted to interface with it.

Comment: All of these crazy tags but you couldn't find a space for [tag:c++]? :( [tag:rad-studio] is labelled as deprecated anyway; you shouldn't be using it.

Comment: Whoops hit enter on CPP 11

Comment: @RemyLebeau I included the .a file and did an nm dump of it. However the problem im now facing is how to alloc and init the object. I can see the methods within the library but can't figure out how to alloc & init the object within CB. Dont know if youve done this before in embarc, will post on there too. [See .a dump here](http://pastebin.com/9VruAL1u)