# Include .a iOS Library in C++ with Embarcadero Rad Studio

Tags: c++, objective-c++

I am trying to include a little static library (.a) containing a simple sum function that I compiled in X-Code for iOS into Embarcadero Rad Studio C++

The closest post I found in the following link but it does not seem to be working as the compiler raises me an error.

[Using Static & Dynamic Libraries In Embarcadero C++ Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32125853/using-static-dynamic-libraries-in-embarcadero-c-builder)

Here is my little C code compiled in X-Code:

```
int c_sum (int a, int b){
  return a+b;  
}
```

The c_lib.h is

```
int c_sum (int a, int b);
```

The compiled version is c_lib.a

I included the .a in the Rad Studio Project and 
 `#include "c_lib.h"`

When I try to call the function the Editor shows up the function prototype but then I compile it is comes out with this error:

> [ld Error]   Error: "__Z5c_sumii", referenced from:
>   __ZN6TForm112Button1ClickEPN6System7TObjectE in .\iOSDevice64\Debug\Unit1.o;

I tried also to include it with pragma #pragma comment(lib, "c_lib.a") same problem.

The purpose of including external libraries is to write specific code in X-Code rather than wrap functions in Embarcadero and use them directly as external static libraries which will be included in my final app.

The second step will be calling methods in objects such as alloc and init.

Can anybody help?!

Comment: Most likely, the declaration of the function in the `.h` file does not match the correct signature of the function in the `.a` file, so the linker can't match function calls in code to the function implementation.

Comment: Hi @RemyLebeau and thank you for your kind answer. I double checked the .a file along with the binary in Hex and the function declaration is exactly the same as in the .h file. 
Is there anything else I should do or check for?
My feelings are that the .a file is not even considered by the linker and the functions prototype shows up just because it is declared in the .h file.
How can I make sure the Linker is locating and loading the .a file?
Any other advise so far?
THB you guys at Embarcadero are doing a great job but you should document better this part in c++.

Comment: I recompiled the library and the problem remains the same:

[ld Error]   Error: "__Z11SumFunctionii", referenced from:      __ZN6TForm112Button1ClickEPN6System7TObjectE in .\\iOSDevice64\\Debug\\Unit1.o; 
[ld Error] ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

Comment: Further discovers tell me that the .a library is not even considered in linking process as if I remove it from project or comment the #pragma line it does not make any difference and the errors are exactly the same?

Any tip?

Comment: this still sounds to me like the compiler is name mangling the function symbol in a way that does not match what is stored in the `.a` file, so the linker can't find the reference. Have you tried dumping the contents of the `.o` and `.a` files to make sure the symbols actually match?

Comment: I included in this file WeTransfer the .a library 
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/fb33eee905f15b371f57179661cd372220181205225629/5986cdcdec60654b6714d55d385181d920181205225629/362b01




I looked up with an Hex Editor and related to my function i found this ASCII:
_OBJC_METACLASS_$_SumLibrary
iPhoneOS11.4.sdk.SumFunction.int.a.b
_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSObject._SumFunction.l_llvm.cmdline.l_llvm .....


My code is the following:
`#import "SumLibrary.h"

@implementation SumLibrary
int SumFunction (int a, int b){
    return a+b;
}
@end
`

Desperate.... :(

Comment: I did an objdump -t of the .a

Here are the results:

 `F __TEXT,__text ltmp0
...
   __TEXT,__objc_classname l_OBJC_CLASS_NAME_
...
   __DATA,__objc_const l_OBJC_METACLASS_RO_$_SumLibrary
...
   __DATA,__objc_const l_OBJC_CLASS_RO_$_SumLibrary
...
   __DATA,__objc_classlist l_OBJC_LABEL_CLASS_$
...
   __LD,__compact_unwind ltmp8
   __DATA,__objc_data _OBJC_CLASS_$_SumLibrary
   __DATA,__objc_data _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SumLibrary
 F __TEXT,__text _SumFunction
   *UND* _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSObject
   *UND* _OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSObject
   *UND* __objc_empty_cache`